# how to get different styles inside textview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How do I set multiple styles for different pieces of text inside a TextView? I have searched it out and found it is possible in Android, but is it possible in iOS? If Yes then how do I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at the attributedText property of UITextView?

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai Of course it does.

Comment: @rmaddy they are different things in Android and iOS

Comment: Thank you rmaddy, it worked for me.I needed to check attributed text so that i can manage particular portion of textview to different shape! and @BlackHatSamurai, iOS has Textview and you're giving negative marks for that. I am wonder.

Comment: I didn't downvote :) You probably got marked down because you don't have any code, and it's not a well written question.

Comment: okay anyways My issue got solved that is imp thing. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextView has an attribute called attributedText that you can call upon, see:
[Accessing the Text Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW13)
You can also set some of the attributes in the Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder.

Comment: Glad to hear to Amit! Have a great day :)